# python recursive yield to reduce memory footprint

Tags: python, recursion, yield

I have a function like below which recursively split a big array into two subarrays, and collect all of them for future processing. My question is if there is a way to yield subarray during splitting process to reduce memory footprint, for example, the array called by split is huge, ~50G.

```
def split(array, subarrays):
    n = len(array)
    if n == 1:
        return
    else:
        i = n / 2
        subarray1 = array[:i]
        subarrays.append(subarray1)
        subarray2 = array[i:]
        subarrays.append(subarray2)
        split(subarray1, subarrays)
        split(subarray2, subarrays)
        return 

subarrays = []
# In production, range(10) will be replaced with a huge array, e.g. 50G
split(range(10), subarrays)
for i in subarrays:
    print i
    # do some other stuff with each subarray
```

Comment: Assuming you read the entire 50G array into memory before splitting, your current function will create many redundant copies of slices of that same data. It's also not necessary to sort the subarrays into ascending order of length afterwards, because the bigger ones will all have been appended before the smaller ones. What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: Right, sorting isn't necessary. I have updated the last part of the code. I just want to split the big array, and apply a function to each of the subarrays

Comment: Your code ends up subdividing the original array down into subarrays of 1 element each — i.e. essentially the original array with each element in a degenerate 1 element subarray (plus all those redundant slices I previously mentioned). Thus it sounds like you just want to apply some function to each element of the original array, correct? If not, what's the upper limit on the size of a subarrays you think would be acceptable (because you only need to subdivide the original down to that point).

Comment: P.S. I also doubt you can read 50GB of data or elements into memory all at once (much less create many copies of it). What format is this data in and where is it coming from (calculated, a file, some device)? Depending on that, it may be possible to figure out a way to process it incrementally.

Comment: It's binary split the big array, think it as a binary tree and I need to apply a function to each of the node on the tree, not just the bottom ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here. Yes, you can use `yield` to return the subarrays one by one. But they won't be in sorted order, and the splitting process will still roughly double your memory usage. But I guess that's better than increasing it 35-fold, which is what'd happen using your code on a 50G list.

```
def split(array):
    n = len(array)
    if n == 1:
        return
    else:
        i = n // 2
        subarray1 = array[:i]
        subarray2 = array[i:]
        yield subarray1
        yield subarray2

        for a in split(subarray1):
            yield a
        for a in split(subarray2):
            yield a

for a in split(range(16)):
    print a
```

**output**

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6, 7]
[0, 1]
[2, 3]
[0]
[1]
[2]
[3]
[4, 5]
[6, 7]
[4]
[5]
[6]
[7]
[8, 9, 10, 11]
[12, 13, 14, 15]
[8, 9]
[10, 11]
[8]
[9]
[10]
[11]
[12, 13]
[14, 15]
[12]
[13]
[14]
[15]
```

Comment: Why 35-fold? How it's calculated?

Comment: This works, and results in using much less memory. But the `memoryview` approach described by @m00am is also interesting, in which case there won't be many data copying around. Unfortunately, I cannot make it to work of numpy array of strings.

Comment: Doesn't it matter that this is yielding the same elements multiple times?

Comment: @zyxue: Sorry, 35-fold was just a rough estimate based on 50G ~= 2**35. The true requirement's actually quite a bit less, mostly because we're not simply splitting a list of bytes down to the individual byte. Each level of your tree requires _roughly_ the same amount of memory as the original level; it's actually a bit less because Python lists are implemented as arrays of pointers. Each subarray requires its own pointers, but the integer objects they're pointing to are shared. On a 32 bit system, a pointer requires 4 bytes (on a 64 bit system the pointers are 8 bytes).

Comment: (cont) A Python integer object requires 12 bytes (at least, it does so on my 32 bit system). If the top list of your binary tree requires 50,000,000,000 bytes then it will contain approximately 3.125 billion integers. That will give you a binary tree of 32 levels, and each level will require approximately 12.5 GB for the pointers. So the total tree will consume approximately 400 GB for the pointers, plus 37.5 GB for the integer objects, making a total of roughly 437.5 GB. That's somewhat under 9 times the RAM required by the initial list alone.

Comment: @martineau: Each list that's yielded is unique. Sure, the elements appear in multiple lists, but that's what the OP wants.

Comment: Maybe passing around the subarrays is too much, what about just passing the indexes that indicate which part of the entire array is needed, keeping the entire array globally available?

Comment: @zyxue: Do you really have enough RAM to hold the whole array in memory? It's better just to hold the required indices in memory and only load small parts of the data from the disk as needed.

Comment: Yes I have about 100G memory

Comment: In that case, loading the whole thing will certainly allow you to do your processing faster than doing it with chunks loaded off disk. You can use tuples to hold the indices for the subarrays, eg `(64, 127)` would represent the slice `bigarray[64:127]`.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using a [memoryview](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview), Eli Bendersky has written a nice [blog entry](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/11/28/less-copies-in-python-with-the-buffer-protocol-and-memoryviews) on this.

I'll try to sum it up though. When creating a memoryview on an object you are creating a reference to a (ctype) datastructure in memory in which the object is stored. A memoryview slice is a reference where to look in this datastructure to find certain values. You can create several views on the same underlying structure without the need to copy anything. This works just like slicing a list or array.

You data has to support the buffer protocol for that though (numpy arrays and bytearrays do that, but lists do not).

I think it would be enough to add this line

```
memview = memoryview(yourarray)
```

to your code and pass it into split instead of your array.

Mind two things though:

- You are working on one big array, so changes to one part of the array (made in one slice) propagate to all other slices covering this value.
- Your results are now memoryview objects. To prints them you need to cast them first (for example to a list).

Example:

```
>>> memview = memoryview("abcde")
>>> print memview
<memory at 0xfoo>
>>> print list(memview)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

>>> mv_slice = memview[3:]
>>> print list(mv_slice)
['d', 'e']

>>> mv_slice[0] = 'y'
>>> print list(mv_slice)
['y', 'e']

>>> print list(memview)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'y', 'e']
# note that the change propagated to the main memoryview
```

All this of course assumes, that you can load 50GB into memory at one point. If you can't do that you should take a look at the [mmap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html) module.

## Edit - numpy arrays of strings

> Will memoryview work with a numpy array of strings?
>
> seems not. e.g. `memview = memoryview(np.array(["abcde", 'aa']))`, `memview[0] is 'abcde'`, but `memview[1]` is `'aa\x00\x00\x00'`

Well, technically it does work. It is just showing how numpy stores arrays of strings. That is: badly ;)

If you create a numpy array of strings like this:

```
>>> npa = np.array(["abcde", 'aa'])
>>> print repr(npa)
array(['abcde', 'aa'],
  dtype='|S5')
```

You see that the dtype is `|S5`, meaning strings of length 5. The 'missing' positions of the shorter strings are padded with empty (zero) bytes (`\x00`) (which numpy normally hides from us for convenience). This is because numpy uses a contiguous 2D array to store the strings in memory to allow for really fast random access.

This means, that all entries in your array consume as much memory as the longest of your strings.
Imagine this, highly constructed, array as an extreme example:

```
strings = ["foobar"*100000] + ["f" for _ in xrange(10000)]
huge_npa = np.array(strings, dtype=str)
```

It contains one very long string (600.000 characters, each 1 byte) and 10.000 strings of only 1 byte. So the total memory consumption should be somewhere around 600KB. If you create this array though it takes up **6GB** of memory.

```
Expected:
1 string * 6 bytes * 100.000 => 600.000 * 1 byte = 600 KB
10.000 strings * 1 byte      =>  10.000 * 1 byte =  10 KB
total                                              610 kB

Reality:
10.000 strings * 6 bytes * 10.0000 => 6.000.000.000 * 1 byte = 6 GB
```

If your strings differ greatly in size you might be wasting a lot of memory here. Maybe you should reconsider using numpy arrays for this.

Comment: seems not. e.g. `memview = memoryview(np.array(["abcde", 'aa']))`, `memview[0]` is `'abcde'`, but `memview[1]` is `'aa\x00\x00\x00'`

Comment: @zyxue: You should have mentioned in your question that this data is on disk. For all _we_ know, you have some amazing system with a huge amount of RAM. :) But definitely take a look at the mmap module. And you might like to write a new question that explains what you're actually trying to do with the data, so we can give you more explicit advice. Please don't change this question now that it has been answered, but you can link your new question to ths one if you think it will help readers.

Answer (score 1):

this will actually increase memory footprint. each time you slice a list, you get a new list in addition to the old one.

e.g.:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]  # great, we have 4 references to objects in this list
l2 = l[:2]        # ok, now we have an additional list with 2 more references
```

what you really want to do is read in the original data in chunks.

Comment: Could you please describe some more details about reading in chunks?

Comment: yeah, so if you have a file with lines in it, read in 10000 lines at a time as opposed to the whole thing. or just read a certain number of bytes, make sure it's properly formatted (e.g. ends in a comma), and go from there.

Comment: Good to know slicing results in copies of a list

Comment: @zyxue: FWIW, making a complete slice of a list is a common way of making a shallow copy. Eg if `a` is a list, then `b=a[:]` makes `b` a shallow copy of `a`.